# [trace32]Error while reading physical image addresses from relocatable data

Tags: image, trace32

When I load a dump of SM8150 5G modem dump.
Trace32 show:

> "Error while reading physical image addresses from relocatable data."

But I double check my `*.elf` file, it is match with the dump files.
I don't know the cause of the error.

Do you can help me ?

My `*.elf` file, it is match with the dump files.

---

log:

> Fatal error detected. Scripts stack printed to C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\std_debug_pmacro.log

---

error log :

> *******************gosub Z:\P4\QC_XY_1750_55\MAIN\Combination\SM8150_SDX50M\LA1.5.2_TN2.2\code\common\Core\tools\cmm\common\std_fatalexit.cmm "Error while reading physical image addresses from relocatable data. " from line 124

Comment: add a log :*************&result = "FAILURE - Relocated data not found at : 0x146BF94C"

Comment: I don't think that this is a general problem with you debugger. I suggest to ask the author of the script std_fatalexit.cmm, who is probably located in your company.